# Running SpringBoot application that implements CommandLineRunner with Cuccumber, run's main application before running Feature test cases

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cucumber

I am new to Cucumber and Spring Boot,I am developeing an Spring Boot application that implements CommandLineRunner and trying to integrate it with Cucumber Framework to run some tests and create corresponding reports.
Now my Cucumber test cases are running fine but before running test cases its runs my Springboot application (Application.java). Is this the expected behaviour or is there someway just to run my tests only.

Main Spring Boot class - Application.java Class:-

```
/**
 * Main Application Class
 */
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {
 @Override
 public void run(String... args) {
 @Autowired
    private GWMLController gwmlController;

    @Autowired
    private SmartXmlController mxMLController;

    @Autowired
    private ReportingController reportingController;

    @Autowired
    private ComparisionReportController comparisionReportController;
    ....
    ...
    My busniess logic 
}
```

Now My Cucumber Class are:-

1. AbstractDefination.java

   ```
   package cucumberJava.steps;

   import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
   import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
   import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;
   import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
   import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;

   @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
   @ActiveProfiles("test")
   @SpringBootTest
   @AutoConfigureMockMvc
   @WebAppConfiguration
   public class AbstractDefinitions{

       public AbstractDefinitions() {
       }

   }
   ```
2. TestValidations:-

   ```
   import static junit.framework.TestCase.assertEquals;
   import static junit.framework.TestCase.assertFalse;
   import static junit.framework.TestCase.assertNotNull;

   @ContextConfiguration(classes = {CucumberConfiguration.class})
   public class TestValidations extends AbstractDefinitions {

   @Autowired
   private GWMLController gwmlController;

   @Autowired
   private SmartXmlController mxMLController;

   @Autowired
   private ComparisionReportController comparisionReportController;

   @Given("^GID map is not empty$")
   public void guid_map_is_not_null() throws Throwable {
     comparisonResultMap = 
     comparisionReportController.makeComparisionMappingMap
    (comparisonResultMap);
    assertFalse(comparisonResultMap.isEmpty());
   }
   ```
3. CucumberConfiguration .java

   ```
   @Configuration
   @ComponentScan(basePackages = "au.com.nab.mx")
   public class CucumberConfiguration {

   }
   ```

And in my build.gradle i have:-

```
 testCompile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-
 test', version: '1.5.4.RELEASE'
 compile group: 'net.sf.supercsv', name: 'super-csv', version: '2.4.0'
 compile group: 'info.cukes', name: 'cucumber-java', version: '1.2.5'
 compile group: 'info.cukes', name: 'cucumber-core', version: '1.2.5'
 compile group: 'info.cukes', name: 'gherkin', version: '2.12.2'
 testCompile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-simple', version: '1.6.1'
 testCompile group: 'info.cukes', name: 'cucumber-spring', version: '1.2.5'
 testCompile group: 'info.cukes', name: 'cucumber-junit', version: '1.2.5'
}
```

.Feature

Feature: Validations.feature

```
  Scenario Outline: COMPARE_COLUMNS
    Given GID map is not empty
    When  <smt> not-null and <gwml> not null
    Then <smt> validateEqual <gwml>

   @Smoke
   Examples:
   |  smt             |  gwml             |
   |  **SMT_GUID      |  **GWML_GUID      |
   |  SMT_BUY_SELL    |  GWML_BUY_SELL    |
```

Now My issue is whenever i run my application, it first runs my Application.java and then its runs my Cucumber test cases.Now i am not sure whether its expected befhaviour or i am missing something.

Regards,
Vikram Pathania

Comment: It is the expected behaviour as test loads the spring`s container and its context before testing the scenarios and it is due to the presence of @SpringBootTest

Comment: Thanks Barath for the answer. Is there some way i can avoid this because i think i need to use @SpringBootTest for my context to load.

Comment: we can avoid it by testing the running application by defining scenarios from the behaviour perspective . What u have written is more or like integration test testing the controller s and services. Rather test the scenarios by just making REST calls to the running application

Answer (score 2):

The answer is - yes it is expected behavior, as result of using SpringRunner.class and @SpringBootTest and @ContextConfiguration annotations.

Answer (score 1):

Usage of @ContextConfiguration and @SpringBootTest will load the application context required for testing.

Docs : 
http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/context/SpringBootTest.html